# How to word wrap the header column in Slickgrids

Tags: css, slickgrid

I ve recently started working with slickgrids. So getting lots and lots of doubts. How can wordwrap the column headers in slickgrids

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by editing 2 css tags:

In `slick-default-theme.css`:

```
.slick-header-columns {
    white-space: pre !important;
    height: 45px;
}
```

The `height` here is adjustable to your needs. This was good to display 3 lines.

In `slick.grid.css`, change the `height` settings on the below tag to `100%`:

```
.slick-header-column.ui-state-default {
    ...
    height: 100%;
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Strange... it didn't work for me when putting the .slick-header-columns; instead I added the white-space property to the .slick-header-column.ui-state-default, which worked.

Answer (score 4):

fwiw, the author of slick grid answers this question here:
https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/61

Answer (score 1):

I created a custom css class to enable/disable the functionality :

```
.slickgrid-word-wrap .slick-cell {
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And then on my `div` container :

```
<div id="my-grid"
     class="slickgrid-word-wrap"></div>
```

And you can still set the row's height on the SlickGrid configuration like this :

```
var options = {
            editable: false,
            enableCellNavigation: false,
            autoExpandColumns: false,
            forceFitColumns: false,
            showFooterRow: false,
            explicitInitialization: true,
            multiColumnSort: false,
            rowHeight: 50 // <--- here
        };
```